# program for finding Gcd in Prolog

Tags: prolog, greatest-common-divisor

I tried to write a code in Prolog for finding GCD (without using modulo) 
can anyone tell me what's wrong with this program?

```
gcd(X,Y,Z):- X>=Y, X1=X-Y, gcd(X1,Y,Z).
gcd(X,Y,Z):- X<Y, X1=Y- X, gcd(X1,X,Z).
gcd(0,X,X):- X>0.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to why the original implementation doesn't work, there are two reasons:

*The predicate `=/2` is for unification, not arithmetic assignment*

The expression `X1 = X - Y` doesn't subtract `Y` from `X` and store the result in `X1`. Rather, it unifies `X1` with the term, `-(X,Y)`. If, for example, `X=5` and `Y=3`, then the result would be, `X1=5-3`, not `X1=2`. The solution is to use `is/2` which assigns evaluated arithmetic expressions: `X1 is X - Y`.

*Other predicates, besides the base case predicate, successfully match the base case*

The clause, `gcd(0,X,X) :- X > 0.` is a reasonable base case, but it is never attempted because the second clause (`gcd(X,Y,Z):- X<Y,...`) will always successfully match the same conditions first, leading to infinite recursion and a stack overflow.

One way to fix this is to move the base case to the first clause, and use a cut to avoid backtracking after it successfully executes:

```
gcd(0, X, X):- X > 0, !.
gcd(X, Y, Z):- X >= Y, X1 is X-Y, gcd(X1,Y,Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z):- X < Y, X1 is Y-X, gcd(X1,X,Z).
```

This will work now:

```
| ?- gcd(10,6,X).

X = 2 ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?- gcd(10,5,X).

X = 5 ? ;

no
```

(NOTE: the "no" here means no more solutions found after finding the first one)

---

**ADDENDUM**

There are still a couple of remaining "gaps" in the above implementation. One is that it doesn't handle `gcd(0, 0, R)` gracefully (it overflows). Secondly, it doesn't handle negative values. One possible solution would be to elaborate these cases:

```
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X < 0, !,
    gcd(-X, Y, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    Y < 0, !,
    gcd(X, -Y, Z).
gcd(X, 0, X) :- X > 0.
gcd(0, Y, Y) :- Y > 0.
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X > Y, Y > 0,
    X1 is X - Y,
    gcd(Y, X1, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X =< Y, X > 0,
    Y1 is Y - X,
    gcd(X, Y1, Z).
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead:

```
gcd(X, 0, X):- !.
gcd(0, X, X):- !.
gcd(X, Y, D):- X =< Y, !, Z is Y - X, gcd(X, Z, D).
gcd(X, Y, D):- gcd(Y, X, D).
```

Taken from [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Prolog) on GCD in all kinds of languages.

Comment: It's correct.. do you have any idea why my original program is wrong ?( except the "is" operation).

Answer (score 1):

**Prolog code for GCD**

```
gcd(X,Y,G) :- X=Y, G=X.
gcd(X,Y,G) :- X<Y, Y1 is Y-X, gcd(X,Y1,G).
gcd(X,Y,G) :- X>Y ,gcd(Y,X,G).

?- gcd(24,16,G).
G = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gc(X,Y,Z):- (
    X=0 -> (
        Z is Y
    );
    Y=0 -> (
        Z is X
    );
    X=Y -> (
        Z is X
    );
    X>Y -> (
        Y1 is X-Y,
        gc(Y1,Y,Z)
    );
    X<Y->(
        Y1 is Y-X,
        gc(X,Y1,Z)
    )
).
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

prolog answer is:-

```
gcd(X,0,X).
gcd(X,Y,R):-
Y>0,
X1 is X mod Y,
gcd(Y,X1,R).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gcd(A,B,X):- B=0,X=A.

gcd(A,B,X):- A>B, gcd(B, A, X).

gcd(A,B,X) :- A<B, T is B mod A, gcd(A, T, X).
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and Readable Prolog Code for GCD of Two Numbers using the Euclidean Algorithm.**

```
gcd(A,B,X):- A=0,X=B. % base case
gcd(A,B,X):- B=0,X=A. % base case
gcd(A,B,X):- A>B, gcd(B, A, X).
gcd(A,B,X):- A<B, T is B mod A, gcd(A, T, X).
```

**Query as follows:**

```
gcd(147,210,GCD).
```

**Output:**

```
GCD = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked.

gcd(X,X,X).

gcd(X,Y,D):-X<Y, Y1 is Y-X, gcd(X,Y1,D).

gcd(X,Y,D):-Y<X, gcd(Y,X,D).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).